# Rpi2 Win10IoT refuses to set serial baud rate higher than 921600

Tags: c++, uwp, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core, servo

I'm currently creating a C++ UWP app that will run on a Rpi2/3 controlling 18 AX12A servos for a robotspider project.

The servos work on a baud rate of 1000000 as default and i would like to leave them like that. The Rpi2 allows everything up to 921600. While the Rpi3 does allow a 1mbps baud rate we wont be using it but cause of the uart and bluetooth sharing the serial connection receiving data from the servos is difficult.

Is it possible to set the baud rate higher than 921600 on the Rpi2 with Win10IoT?
We are currently running the latest Windows Insider build (16193) on the Rpis.

Comment: Yes, Rpi3 with version 16193 does work with 1M baud rate. What's error when setting baud rate higher than 921600 on Rpi2?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT The error we where getting is Feature not supported, for now our work around is by setting the servos on half the speed so it works with the rpi2